# Upload blob data to Cloudinary

Tags: javascript, image, meteor, blob, cloudinary

I have a Meteor application and I am trying to extract some images from `.epub` files and then save them to Cloudinary but I am not having any luck. Here is what I've done thus far:

Using `epub.js` I load the `.epub` file and read the image data:

```
 const book = ePub('path_to_file.epub');
 const cover = book.coverUrl();
/* cover._result returns this:
"blob:http://localhost:3000/6433bd4e-13dc-462b-b7be-e9654ad06c18"
*/
```

I can manually assign `cover._url` to an image source and the image renders as expected:

```
  $('#bookImage').attr('src', cover._result)
```

I have tried to upload the `cover._result` , `"blob:http://localhost:3000/6433bd4e-13dc-462b-b7be-e9654ad06c18"` like so:

```
  Cloudinary.upload( cover._result,{
    folder: 'Books',
    resource_type: 'raw',
  },function(err, res){ 
    if (err){ 
      console.log(err); 
    } else { 
      console.log(res);
       } 
     });
```

and I get no response

I also tried this:

```
const myFile = new File([cover._result], "new_file.jpg", {type: "image/jpg"}); 
Cloudinary.upload( myFile,{...})
```

The file uploads, BUT its garbage data and not readable

Lastly I tried converting the file to base64 like so:

```
 const toDataUrl = function(cover, callback) {
 const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      callback(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', cover);
  xhr.send();
}

/******************/
      toDataUrl (cover._result, function( base64Img ) {
        Cloudinary.upload( base64Img,{
          folder: 'Books',
           resource_type: 'raw',
         },function(err, res){ 
            if (err){ 
              console.log(err); 
            } else { 
              console.log(res);
            } 
        });
    })
```

I get no response from the `Cloudinary.upload` function.

My question is, Does Cloudinary support this type of functionality?

Thanks.

**SOLVED**

This was an issue with the Meteor package itself.

I had to change this:

```
  toDataUrl (cover._result, function( base64Img ) {
    Cloudinary.upload( base64Img,{
      folder: 'Books',
       resource_type: 'raw',
     },function(err, res){ 
        if (err){ 
          console.log(err); 
        } else { 
          console.log(res);
        } 
    });
})
```

to this:

```
  toDataUrl (cover._result, function( base64Img ) {
    Cloudinary._upload_file( base64Img,{
      folder: 'Books',
     },function(err, res){ 
        if (err){ 
          console.log(err); 
        } else { 
          console.log(res);
        } 
    });
})
```

And the image data uploaded without issue.

Comment: Hi, What library do you use here: Cloudinary.upload(...); what npm package is it? :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to change this:

```
  toDataUrl (cover._result, function( base64Img ) {
    Cloudinary.upload( base64Img,{
      folder: 'Books',
       resource_type: 'raw',
     },function(err, res){ 
        if (err){ 
          console.log(err); 
        } else { 
          console.log(res);
        } 
    });
})
```

to this:

```
  toDataUrl (cover._result, function( base64Img ) {
    Cloudinary._upload_file( base64Img,{
      folder: 'Books',
     },function(err, res){ 
        if (err){ 
          console.log(err); 
        } else { 
          console.log(res);
        } 
    });
})
```